# Python - Tkinter Radiobuttons highlighting when hovering

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

The problem I am having is that the selection of the radiobutton options in python works as it should, however the options are highlighted after a certain time (if one option has not been selected) if your cursor hovers over them. I am not sure how to stop this happening. I am on python 2.7.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *


class App:

    def __init__(self,master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        label1=Label(root, text="Choose one of the following options:")
        label1.pack(padx=10)

        v = IntVar()

        frame3=Frame()
        frame3.pack(pady=10)

        self.option1=Radiobutton(frame3, text="One", variable=v, value=1).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)
        self.option2=Radiobutton(frame3, text="Two", variable=v, value=2).pack(side= LEFT,padx=5) 
        self.option2=Radiobutton(frame3, text="Three", variable=v, value=3).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)

        frame2=Frame()

        self.submit = Button(frame2, anchor=S, text="Submit", command=self.submit_optn)
        self.submit.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitbutton = Button(frame2,anchor=S, text = "QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.quitbutton.pack(side=LEFT)
        frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)

    def submit_optn(self):
        top=Toplevel()
        top.title("submit")
        label2=Label(top, text="Choice submitted")
        label2.pack(padx=20,pady=10)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `v` to `self.v` and likewise change `v` in the radiobuttons to `self.v`.

It's getting garbage collected